# In a multiprocessor system, will each processor have an independent JVM?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, multiprocessing

Suppose we are having a system with multiple processors. Will each of these processor have their individual JVM? If no, then another question is that in a computer which has two different OS (say Windows and RedHat) partitioned and we have to run a java application on any of them. JVM will be different for both platforms, then how this will work?

Comment: Maybe this is appropriate for a different site... But you probably need to read on how processes work and are managed by operating systems. It will also be useful to understand the concept of threads and how it differs from processes. maybe it's possible to run multiple live operating systems at the same time on one computer, but unless one's using virtual machines or containers, that would make a very tough question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Suppose we are having a system with multiple processors. Will each of
>   these processor have their individual JVM?

No, there will be one JVM instance launched for each program execution, but that JVM may (depending on implementation) use multiple *processes* and most certainly run with multiple *threads*, both of which would be capable of making use of the multi-processor facilities of the system.

> If no, then another
>   question is that in a computer which has two different OS (say Windows
>   and RedHat) partitioned and we have to run a java application on any
>   of them. JVM will be different for both platforms, then how this will
>   work?

You install a separate JVM to each OS. Again, within each OS one would expect a single JVM instance to be launched per program execution, and the above applies again.

Java is "compile once, run anywhere", so as long as the JVM versions are compatible with what you've compiled, it doesn't matter which OS and corresponding JVM you execute it on, it will work exactly the same.

This is because Java bytecode is platform/OS agnostic (it is interpreted by the JVM), while the JVM itself is platform/OS specific.